# semi-circle on top rectangle in android with xml

Tags: android

how can make this shape in android studio with xml?
a semi-circle on top of rectangle.
i want to put profile picture in top and text inside the rectangle.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#201215cc" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: myshape]

Comment: You can use two views, one for profilepic and another for text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="98dp"
        android:height="38dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:top="11dp"
        android:start="1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="18dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:left="11dp"
        android:top="2dp">

        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[Output like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35hjX.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `ConstraintLayout`.

Alight your profile pic in vertical center of top border of your rectangle and apply some start(left) margin to it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_rectangle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/your_view"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="#451245"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/your_rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/your_rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/your_rectangle" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```